# If an incandescent light is rated for 60 watts, can a LED lamp cause an amperage or heat issue in the fixture/enclosure?

Tags: ac, light, electricity, home-automation, zigbee

This question is based on the adage "it's the amperage that kills you"... but in this case I don't want to start a fire.

I have a Philips white and color light that I would like to put in a ceiling mount rated for 60 Watts.

The markings on the new bulb:

- A19
- 10W
- 145 mA.
- 110-130 Vac 50/60Hz
- 800 Lumens

**Question**

1. Can the "fancy colors and dimming" features of this bulb cause an amperage issue that may cause a fire?
2. Is this safe to put 145mAmps into a 60 Watt outlet?
3. When is it not safe for use in such outlet?
4. If Amperage is the danger, what is that threshold / how does it get reached? (this is a dimmable bulb I can ensure is always set to low)
5. Accounting for the rest of it... is the heat of a 60W bulb equal or less than an equivalent LED light? (looking for the function that defines what equivalent is)

Comment: @nick-alexeev I'm looking for the mathematical relationship (ideally a graph) between incandescent lamps and their wattage against LED lamps and their heat/amperage/lumen output.

Comment: I think you need to look up the relationship between volts, amps, and watts. Simply put, look up "Ohm's Law". Your understanding of volts, amps, and watts is clearly very lacking.

Comment: The only relevant characteristic of the LED bulb is whether it is rated for use in fully enclosed fixtures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fixture is rated to handle a 60 W incandescent bulb, it will certainly be safe with a 10 W (LED?) bulb.

Edit in response to comment:

The 10 W bulb will produce much less heat than a 60 W bulb, so there will be no need to be concerned about excessive heat.  The fixture can probably deliver up to 15 Amps (normal North American lighting circuit), but the 10 W bulb will only draw the current it requires - 145 mA for full brightness white, less if dimmed or non-white.

Comment: I made clarifications / edits saying that I'm concerned about amps (or even bulb heat) causing a fire... unless that that is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Your assumption is incomplete and you are missing some very important information. Heat comes from the watts, not just the milliamps. As I mentioned in my initial comment, look up the relationship between volts, amps, and watts.

Comment: @DerStrom8 it's been a while since I did this in high school. Thanks for the pointers. Am reading now.

Comment: "The 10 W bulb will produce much less heat than a 60 W bulb, so there will be no need to be concerned about excessive heat."_ - That is overly optimistic. 10W of heat should be no problem for the enclosure (which is rated for 60W), but LED lamps don't like getting hot and in an enclosed space, 10W could make it hot enough to significantly shorten its lifespan. So excessive heat can certainly be a concern.